# How to do some thing while closing a JFrame window

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

I completed an application that runs multiple threads. Each thread possess a **JFrame** window. 
What I want to do is when a user clicks the **X** to close window, just that specified thread and its window is closed.

```
public ImageShower( VideoStream localStream){

    // Something something

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(rViewer);

    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent){
            localStream.stopWork(); // this part can not access the local stream here. it says that the localStream should be final.
        }
    }); 
}
```

That is what I write, but the localStream can not be accessed inside the method. 
How to deal with that?

Comment: Google broken again? Change your method "header" to `public ImageShower(final VideoStream localStream)`

Answer (score 0):

You should instanciate your streaming Class so that you can respond to its running methods as you like. Or change your code to `public ImageShower(final VideoStream localStream) {}`